# What software/tools was used for this

Tags: website-design, animation

- https://dogstudio.co

Saw this on awwwwards today, and was blown away was just curious what tools/software could have been used to create an interactive background like that.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please [edit] your question to clarify what exact aspect you are referring to, e.g., having a live-rendered 3D background or capturing user action like this. Also be aware that some aspects of this are more about web programming than graphic design and thus we are not the right people to ask. Finally, please summarise whatever about that webpage is relevant to your question here, so your question continues to work should that link die.

Answer (score 1):

The main technology in use is WebGL. As for what tools they used specifically, you'd have to ask them. It's likely the did part of it in a software like Unity.

Comment: TBH its not terribly hard to program that form scratch, mostly ist shader code and polygon dumping.